# Find node neighbors in 2d array

Tags: java

Assume that I have the following (n * n) array:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 a b c
d e f g
```

I want to write a function that finds the neighbor nodes of a given node. For example, for node 1, it will return an array with 2, 6, and 5. For node "a", it will return a vector with node 5, 6, 7, b, f, e, d, and 9. The order does not matter. I tried to do this with only using if-statements, but it turned into a nightmare really quick.

Whats the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: you can do it with a small number of if statements easily enough. please update your question with the code you have tried and people will be more able to help you with it.

Comment: @KLibby  used 4 if-statements for the corner cases, 4 if-statements for the border cases, and 1 if-statements when I have one element in the array and 4 when I have 2 * 2 array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// assume (x,y) is position in array you want to get neighbours from
// assume 'array' is your array with x first and then y
// assume T is type of your array stuff

ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

for (int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
        // check if (i,j) is in array bounds
        if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < array.length() && j < array[i].length()) {
            // the point isn't its own neighbour
            if (i != x && j != y)
                list.add(array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
return list.toArray();
```

EDIT: As your Array is n*n big you don't have to use array.length(), but this way it will work for all kind of array.

Comment: It is much better to encourage the OP to solve the problem themselves, giving hints if necessary. Doing the work for them means they don't learn anything about solving the problem when they can just cut and paste someone elses code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loops, let assume that (i,j) is the location of your element, mat is your array

```
mat[n][n]
int res[8];
int x = 0;
for (int k = i - 1 ; k < 2 ;k++)
    for(int t = j-1 ; j  <2 ;j++)
        if ((k > 0) && (t > 0) && (t<n) && (k < n))
            res[x++] = mat[k][t];
```

Comment: It is much better to encourage the OP to solve the problem themselves, giving hints if necessary. Doing the work for them means they don't learn anything about solving the problem when they can just cut and paste someone elses code.